# groupBy count in lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array of object like this:

```
[
  {
    rating: 1
  },
  {
    rating: 2
  },
  {
    rating: 3
  },
  {
    rating: 1
  }
]
```

I want the result like this -

```
{
  1: 2,
  2: 1,
  3: 1
}
```

It will be `Rating_Value: Count`.

How can I do that in lodash? Or if it can be optimized without lodash?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [lodash#countBy](https://lodash.com/docs#countBy).

```
var result = _.countBy(data, 'rating');
```

```js
var data = [
  {
    rating: 1
  },
  {
    rating: 2
  },
  {
    rating: 3
  },
  {
    rating: 1
  }
];

var result = _.countBy(data, 'rating');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.14.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get this result.

```js
var data = [{"rating":1},{"rating":2},{"rating":3},{"rating":1}];

var result = data.reduce(function(r, e) {
  r[e.rating] = (r[e.rating] || 0) + 1;
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in pure JS like this:

```
var myArr = [
  {
    rating: 1
  },
  {
    rating: 2
  },
  {
    rating: 3
  },
  {
    rating: 1
  }
];

var ratingObject = {};

myArr.forEach(function(valueObject) {
   ratingObject[valueObject.rating] = ratingObject[valueObject.rating] ? ratingObject[valueObject.rating] + 1 : 1;
});
```